# How to configure my website to be accessed by public IP addres

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, remote-access

I have a website hosted on my pc , I can access my website using `127.0.0.1` also `192.168.0.130` but not by using the public IP address .
however I can access the rooter interface using `http://105.101.xxx.xx/` but it should show me the index file 
and when I type `http://105.101.xxx.xx/index.php` instead it shows an error :

> Object Not Found The requested URL '/index.php' was not found on the
> RomPager server.
> my configuration :

- I have port 80 opened and forwarded on my router ( pinging using the public ip is working fine and the port checked)
- In  apache file I have `Listen *:80`
- Also in apache I have `serverName 127.0.0.1:80`
- Also have :

`<Directory "${path}/www"> Allow Override None Order allow,deny Allow from all  </Directory>`
what I'm missing here ?

Comment: The RomPager is an embedded HTTP server on your router, and you are behind a NAT.

Comment: @EsaJokinen thanks for the help , I'm not sure if I understand what you mean i suck when it comes to networking, what is the solution please ?

Comment: Although, what is "I have port 80 opened **and forwarded on my router**" if it's not _port forwarding_?

Comment: try `serverName 105.101.xxx.xxx` (without 80)

Comment: Typically port forwarding doesn't work from inside the NAT, especially when the HTTP interface is already listening on internal:80. Although using the external IP address, your connection to the router comes from the internal interface. This shouldn't really matter, as you are still able to use the service both from the LAN and from the Internet.